# Toggle between seats using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, events

I am designing seating arrangement fo buses. I have written javascript function to create seats dynamically, so that when page loads, it will create the seats. Now I want a condition where User can select only one seat. After selecting one seat if he clicks on the other then previous seat must be deselected. Below is my code.... what must be added to toggle between them?

```
  function createSeats(oSeatsContainer,seatsPerRow,rowNumber){
            for(i=0; i < rowNumber; i++){
                var oRow = document.createElement('tr');
                    for(j=1; j <= seatsPerRow; j++){
                    oCell = document.createElement('td');
                    var oImg = document.createElement('img');
                    oImg.src = statusPics['avail'].src;
                    oImg.status = 'avail';
                    oImg.id = (i*10)+j;
                    oImg.onclick=function(){
                        this.status = (this.status == 'avail')? 'mine' : 'avail';
                        this.src = (this.status == 'avail')? statusPics['avail'].src : statusPics['mine'].src;
                        oTotalprice.innerHTML = '';
                        oBookedSeatNos.innerHTML = '';
                        oBtnCheckout.disabled = true;
                    }
                    oCell.appendChild(oImg);
                    oRow.appendChild(oCell);
                }
                oSeatsContainer.appendChild(oRow);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you bind a single event to the parent container and get the target element using `e.target`.
You can add a `data-seat_id` attribute to your individual seats to uniquely identify them.

```
var selected_seat_id;

oSeatsContainer.onClick = function(e) {
  selected_seat_id = e.target.getAttribute("data-seat_id");
  drawSeats();
}

drawSeats();
```

`drawSeats()` will be similar to the code you wrote above but without the onClick handler and taking into account the `selected_seat_id` to draw an available/taken seat. Also set the `data-seat_id` attribute in the loop.